# Can Arduino take 19.5 V

Tags: power

I have a 19.5 V power adapter, can I safely connect it to my Arduino? I don't want to damage it. It is very simple, just lights some LEDs, and I don't want to burn the LEDs either.

Comment: probably not, but `19.5 V` is not enough information ... what is written on the power adapter label?

Comment: You may want to say which Arduino you have, because there is *some* variation in a specific answer based on that.

Comment: 45 W 19.5 V = 2.31 A

thats exactly what it says

Comment: I have a Arduino Uno Rev3

Comment: https://store.arduino.cc/arduino-uno-rev3 see the Tech Specs tab

Answer (score 1):

You can do it but you will have nothing left from the regulator for LEDs etc. The best solution is to invest in a buck converter, they are only a few dollars from your favorite china supplier, sometimes even less then a buck. While you are at it purchase two or three you can then use them to generate other voltages as you progress with the Arduino. I use this method a lot, it is a way to use my old laptop power supplies. If you do not have one your next purchase should be a multimeter, even a cheap one is better than none. Then a logic analyzer, again less than $10.00 US. You could also purchase a 8 to 12V wall wart with maybe about 2 amp output and be safe while probably costing less then the buck converter. Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

The Arduino Uno has a maximum voltage range of 6 to 20 v and a recommended range of 7 to 12 v

Using it at 19.5 v may work if the power supply is well regulated but it is uncomfortably close to the limits and dropping nearly 15v across the linear regulator on the Uno may cause it to get fairly hot.